# Why doesn't grunt-contrib-connect find the connect task?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I have a very simple grunt setup. The only active plugin is grunt-contrib-connect. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gruntApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "An application for testing Grunt.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0"
  }
}
```

My gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON 'package.json'
    log:
      start: 'Grunt is starting for application <%=pkg.name%> v<%=pkg.version%>'
      end: 'Grunt is finishing'
  grunt.registerMultiTask 'log', ->
    grunt.log.writeln this.data
  grunt.registerTask 'printConfig', ->
    grunt.log.writeln JSON.stringify grunt.config(), null, 2
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-connect'
  grunt.registerTask 'default', [
    'log:start'
    'log:end'
  ]
```

My custom tasks work, but `grunt connect` does not. Here is the output at the console:

```
$ grunt connect -v

Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.coffee" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/eric/Projects/gruntApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/eric/Projects/gruntApp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect
Loading "Gruntfile.coffee" tasks...OK
+ default, log, printConfig

Running tasks: connect

Running "connect" task
>> No "connect" targets found.
Warning: Task "connect" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What up with that, yo? It looks like it detects the connect task, but later it can't find the target. What am I missing? I was following the directions from here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#getting-started

Comment: The only targets I see are `pkg` and `log`. There is no `connect` target. Have a look at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#usage-examples.

Comment: I thought that using `grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-connect'` would load the targets and tasks from that module. Not so, I see that adding the target `connect` to initConfig solves the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring the task + target is an important part of making it available from the command line. To make grunt `connect work`, add configuration to `.initConfig`:

```
grunt.initConfig
  connect:
    server:
      options:
        base: 'app'
        keepalive: true
```